# The type or namespace name 'IMongoDatabase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am getting an error:

> The type or namespace name 'IMongoDatabase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

MongoDB.Driver is in the references folder and I have a using statement for it so i don#t know why this error is happening?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using System.Configuration;
namespace DispatchDivor.Models.MongodbWork
{
    public class MongoOperation
    {

        private IMongoDatabase database;
       List<OfficeCode> listcode;
        public MongoOperation()
        {
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mongoDBHost"]);
            database = mongoClient.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mongoDBName"]);
        }
```

Comment: Is there also an error on `using MongoDB.Driver;` ?

Comment: What version of the diver are you using? What kind of app is this .net or .net core?

Comment: yes sir. there is error on using MongoDB.Driver; . it is already present in references folder and i use it top of the page. But when i rebuild the project then this error show.

Comment: What do you mean by it is in the references folder? There is a difference between adding a reference in a project and just dropping a dll into a folder.

Comment: I mean  MongoDB.Driver library reference  is present. but yet it give an error ..about missing reference.

Comment: Did you register instance of IMongodatabase in the DI pipeline?

Comment: @Urgen, if not (and if it even applies here) it would be a runtime error, not a compile error.

Comment: @Urgen yes dear

Comment: . @Crowcoder it is compile time error .

Comment: I know, that's what I was saying. I just didn't want the comment about a DI pipeline to throw you off track.